# XPath Scrapy Join Text Nodes Separated by br tags in a class

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am learning web scraping with Python, Xpath, and Scrapy. I am stuck with the following. I would be grateful, if you can help me.

This is the HTML code

```
<div class="discussionpost">
“This is paragraph one.”
<br>
<br>
“This is paragraph two."'
<br>
<br>
"This is paragraph three.”
</div>
```

This is the output I would like to get: "This is paragraph one. This is paragraph two. This is paragraph three." I would like to combine all paragraphs separated by the `<br>`. There is no `<p>` tag.

However, the output I am getting is:
"This is sentence one.","This is sentence two.","This is sentence three."

This is the code I am using:

```
sentences = response.xpath('//div[@class="discussionpost"]/text()').extract()
```

I understand why the code above is acting the way it is. But, I could not change it to do what I need to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all text nodes value, You have to invoke `//text()` instead of `/text()`

```
sentences = ' '.join(response.x`path('//div[@class="discussionpost"]//text()').extract()).strip()
```

**Proven by scrapy shell:**

```
>>> from scrapy import Selector
>>> html_doc = '''
... <html>
...  <body>
...   <div class="discussionpost">
...    “This is paragraph one.”
...    <br/>
...    <br/>
...    “This is paragraph two."'
...    <br/>
...    <br/>
...    "This is paragraph three.”
...   </div>
...  </body>
... </html>
...
... '''
>>> res = Selector(text=html_doc)
>>> res
<Selector xpath=None data='<html>\n <body>\n  <div class="discussi...'>
>>> sentences = ''.join(res.xpath('//div[@class="discussionpost"]//text()').extract())
>>> sentences
'\n   “This is paragraph one.”\n   \n   \n   “This is paragraph two."\'\n   \n   \n   "This is paragraph three.”\n  '
>>> txt = sentences
>>> txt
'\n   “This is paragraph one.”\n   \n   \n   “This is paragraph two."\'\n   \n   \n   "This is paragraph three.”\n  '
>>> txt = sentences.replace('\n','').replace("\'",'').replace('    ','').replace("“",'').replace('”','').replace('"','').strip()
>>> txt
'This is paragraph one. This is paragraph two. This is paragraph three.'
>>>
```

**Update:**

```
import scrapy
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ibsgroup.org/threads/hemorrhoids-as-cause-of-pain.363290/']
     
    def parse(self, response):
        for p in response.xpath('//*[@class="bbWrapper"]'):
            yield {
            'comment': ''.join(p.xpath(".//text()").getall()).strip()
            }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! I tried your approach. When I save the results to a csv, it seems that every letter has a unique index value. Am I missing something with your answer? It looks exactly what I need. But, in the csv file, I like each message, whether it has 1 or 5 paragraphs, to have one index value.

Comment: Use space in empty join like:   '   '.join(). see the above edit.

Comment: Thanks for your response? Do you mean sentences = ' '.join() vs sentences = ''.join() ? I tried both and not seeing anything different in the csv file. When I loop through the sentences list, I see an individual letter in each iteration not a complete online discussion message. My apologies if I am confusing you.

Comment: I think, You are doing things wrong.  would you update with your full code?

Comment: From the sentences, you are getting  plain string. Not a list of stings. You can iterate but you have to remove join() method

Comment: Certainly. Here is my full code.

This is the online discussion I am trying to scrape:
https://www.ibsgroup.org/threads/hemorrhoids-as-cause-of-pain.363290/


#comments = ''.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="bbWrapper"]//text()').extract()).strip()


for comment in comments:
    test_dictionary["Comment"].append(comment)


test_dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(test_dictionary)

test_dataframe.to_csv('commenttest.csv', index=True, index_label="Index")

Comment: Thank you so much! I sincerely appreciate your time and effort. I learned something new.